# Shipping/ Billing Address issue on 'Review your information page' paypal page

Tags: paypal, billing, ubercart

We have an online gift shop using Ubercart linked to PayPal. The purpose of our website is to purchase gifts to be sent to various shipping addresses (recipients). We are posting this request as the website owners on behalf of our developers so please excuse any incorrect technical references used!

Our issue is when Customers input their billing address and also recipient's shipping address, which both show correctly on Ubercart on our website.The problem starts when customer is redirected to PayPal  payment(checkout page) where PayPal shows the shipping address that is in fact a Billing address. This causes confusion of customers thinking that the gift they want to be sent to someone else is going to be sent  to their address. We are using WPS - standard business solution from PayPal.

We would like to find out:
 #. If on PayPal checkout page can "Shipping Address" title be changed to "Billing Address" title or #. Is there an option where NO ADDRESS is shown- we have found this on a UK website for flowers under www.bunches.co.uk

Any other suggestions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to change the title of the shipping address to billing address.  There are also not parameters specifically for shippping address that you can pass over with Website Payments Standard.  If your cart supports it, you may want to use Express Checkout instead of Website Payments Standard.  Express Checkout would give you more control over the checkout flow, and you would be able to pass over a specific shipping address using the shipping variables.  Also i am not sure what you are rferring to by no address showing.  ARe you referring to no shipping address or no shipping address or billing address is being displayed?  If you do not want any shipping address displayed, you can use the variable **no_shipping** and set it one of the values below.  But keep in mind that if you set it to not require a shipping address you will not get a shipping address in your details if you are shipping items.

```
0 – prompt for an address, but do not require one 
1 – do not prompt for an address 
2 – prompt for an address, and require one
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your response. We are sending this on to our website developers. Once again much appreciated. I think the solution you have outlined with the 1- do not prompt for an address may address our issue.